# jquery multiple file upload limit number of files not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Jquery multiple file upload with ajax.

```
option : {  
    limitMultiFileUploads : 3    
}
```

is not working for jquery file upload.

This is what i did :

```
$(function() {        
        $('#attachUpload').fileupload({            
            dataType: 'json',
            limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
            option:
                {
                    maxFileSize: 40000,
                    maxNumberOfFiles: 2
                },
            start: function(e) {
                $('.btn-sent').unbind('click'); // important - remove all event handlers
            },
            done: function(e, data) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(data._response.jqXHR.responseText);
                doneflag--;
                if (doneflag == 0) {                                              
                        $('#frmCompose').submit();                       
                }
            },
            submit: function(e, data) {                
                data.formData = setFormData();                
            },
            add: function(e, data) {
            }
});
```

but filesize limit and number of files limit not working can anyone help please.

Comment: What is the observed behaviour?

Comment: on submit files are uploading but files should not be uploaded when files limit is is crossed.

Comment: What do you want to do? A limit of 2 upload at the same time or 2 upload for every session?

Comment: A limit of max 2 upload at the same time only.

Comment: Another why not working question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551539/jquery-file-upload-how-to-limit-number-of-files-uploaded

Answer (score 2):

You are actually looking for `maxNumberOfFiles` option.

More details on the doc: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

My working code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: '../uploaderDemo/server/php/',
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp3|wav)$/i
    });
```

Comment: Keep in mind `maxNumberOfFiles` and `acceptFileTypes` only work when using the UI version of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the object with the name "option" and put the two settings at the same level as the rest of the options.

```
 $(function() {        
            $('#attachUpload').fileupload({            
                dataType: 'json',
                limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
                maxFileSize: 40000,
                maxNumberOfFiles: 2,
                start: function(e) {
                    $('.btn-sent').unbind('click'); // important - remove all event handlers
                },
                done: function(e, data) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(data._response.jqXHR.responseText);
                    doneflag--;
                    if (doneflag == 0) {                                              
                            $('#frmCompose').submit();                       
                    }
                },
                submit: function(e, data) {                
                    data.formData = setFormData();                
                },
                add: function(e, data) {
                }
    });
```